# YouTube URL attribution_link - what is it?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I build URLs for going directly to a comment or reply on my YouTube site. It works fine, except the video sometimes (often) starts to play. I'm using this URL to reply to a comment, so I don't want the video to play. It's not a big deal, except it's annoying.

Here's the URL syntax I'm currently using:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=&lc=

I also tried adding this to the end: "&feature=em-comments" but it didn't make a difference.

I'd love to use the URL syntax that comes in the email, but I don't know what an "attribution_link" is.

Anyone got any ideas?